# Hermitian matrix and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

It is true that: Every eigenvalue of a Hermitian matrix is real.

But does this mean that : if all of the eigenvalues of a matrix is real, then the matrix is Hermitian?

Answer (score 2):

Any real nonsymmetric matrix is not Hermitian. For example, \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
And eigenvalues are only 0. (This does not mean any real valued matrix have only real eigenvalues, I mean we can find very simple examples instead of using complex number containing $i$)

Comment: The zero matrix is, however, Hermitian.

Comment: sorry for that mistake, i rewrote my answer

Answer (score 1):

NO. Take, for instance $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&i\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$$